# PLS in R and Model Extraction

Tags: r

I'm not sure if this is a CV question or one for here....

Ive run a PLS model on my data in R using the plsr() function from {pls} package. My data had one Y response Variable and 30 X Inputs variables. My Model works well with 9 Comps and predicts well on new unseen data. My question is how does one go about extracting the Model Coefficients rather than using the predict() function in R...I want to see the linear combination/model equation...? can it be done..?

Sorry I know I havn't added example data/code here but I'm hoping its not required based on what Ive asked.

Comment: "I havn't added example data/code here but I'm hoping its not required based". I am afraid it is.

Comment: Usually a `coef` function is implemented. Try `coef(x)` or `coef(summary(x))`. See `?coef.mvr` for details (`plsr` returns a "mvr" object).